# useradd command truncates the password mentioned with -p option

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, passwd, shadow

Command is as below, which is executed on wind river linux manchine.

```
useradd vpatest -c Pav -g guest -G log -s /data/bin/cli.sh -p $6$cem^CM38$4YdQAPgu8EXNG3ecurYk4eN1sIiYNauBdHFRJew3l/Xa8PyOjACD1xNDhoocVwBzBUN9BlTXXJ/oiWHwV.fhL1
```

In the `/etc/shadow` file it is writing only

`YdQAPgu8EXNG3ecurYk4eN1sIiYNauBdHFRJew3l/Xa8PyOjACD1xNDhoocVwBzBUN9BlTXXJ/oiWHwV.fhL1` and truncating `$6$cem^CM38$4`

Any way to avoid this and write the full password? I will get encrypted password and need to write as it is in the shadow file. Otherwise, is any other utilities that can be used?

Comment: can you use it inside `''`?

Comment: well, `$6` and `$4` are positional parameters, and `$cem` is a valid variable, so they'll be expanded by the shell. Though `^` isn't a valid part of a variable name, so I can't see why the `^CM38` part would disappear. Put the string in single quotes to prevent the parameter expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Since your input string (password) contains characters that can be interpreted by the shell to have a special meaning (for ex. `$`), wrap the password string inside a pair of `''`, like

```
 useradd vpatest -c Pav -g guest -G log -s /data/bin/cli.sh -p '$6$cem^CM38$4YdQAPgu8EXNG3ecurYk4eN1sIiYNauBdHFRJew3l/Xa8PyOjACD1xNDhoocVwBzBUN9BlTXXJ/oiWHwV.fhL1'
```